# What NIAC investigations were implemented in real spaceflight? (NASA Innovative Advanced Concepts)

Tags: nasa, technology, conceptual

[NIAC](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/niac/index.html) as in *the NASA Institute for Advanced Concepts* wasn't founded until 1998, so such futuristic concepts might not have come to fruition much yet. But I'd like to hear of any, or of what the expectations and purposes of NIAC is. Is it for example intended to stimulate the creativity of the staff? To attract creative people who want a serious shot at designing a real space mission one day? To be a part of NASA's organizational culture?

[Here](https://livestream.com/viewnow/NIAC2017) are videos of the NIAC 2017 presentations, with schedule at the bottom of the video list.